# What would be a good architecture and framework for a single-page web app to run on an embedded, battery-powered device?

Tags: reactjs, embedded, single-page-application, alpine.js, preact

My company sells hardened battery-powered wireless sensors which connect to a central hub unit (also wireless and battery powered) which uses the QP platform RT OS from Quantum Leaps, though I believe the actual web server is running on a separate WiFi module that its connected to (GainSpan 2100E).

We are trying to re-write an embedded web application to run on that device. Previously they wrote it in pure JavaScript and HTML but that was brittle and had a lot of unnecessary code repetition. I was thinking of making the new one with a lightweight version of React, possibly using Preact or Alpine, but I don't know if these are the best choices. We want to keep it as lightweight as possible, and limit the amount of server calls from the browser since every bit of data transferred reduces battery life, but we absolutely need to keep the actual sensor data up to date on the browser so the user can see it in almost real time.

Comment: No real advice to offer, but you will need to be careful in what you mean when you say you're looking for "lightweight". Most libraries develop around bundle size, or how much data is sent over the wire to users' browsers, but I get the sense you're more looking for lightweight as in raw file size, which is more of a build tooling / architecture issue. The main JS library will likely be a small portion of the total size on disk.